# SEO friendly URL using smarty php?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, smarty

I am using smarty PHP in my project.

normally I use the following code in smarty to create links and point them to their specific URL's:

in my smarty template page:

```
{section name=title loop=$title}
<li><a class="nav" href="index.php?url={$title[title].url}">{$title[title].title}</a></li>
{/section}
```

the code above will generate the following URL:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?url=somename.html
```

the `somename.html` is stored in the mysql database.

in my index.php file I get the details of the url=someone.html like so:

in my smarty template page:

```
{if isset($smarty.get.url)} 


  {$body}

  {/if}
```

and in my php page:

```
if(isset($_GET['url']))
{
    include "config/connect.php";

    $url = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['url']);
    $url=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_GET['url']);
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx, "SELECT id, url, title, body FROM pages WHERE url=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $url);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $url, $title, $body);
    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);





$pageurl=$_GET['url'];
    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
}
/* close connection */
mysqli_close($db_conx);


$smarty->assign('id', $id);
$smarty->assign('url', $url);

$smarty->assign('title', $title);
$smarty->assign ('body', $body);
```

This all works fine up to this point.

the question I have is this:

I am trying to create SEO friendly URL's.

example:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?url=somename.html
```

to

```
http://domain.com/somename.html
```

I have this code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ index.php?url=$1
```

the code above will allow me to convert `http://domain.com/index.php?url=somename.html`

to `http://domain.com/somename.html`

BUT,

when I view `http://domain.com/somename.html` in the browser, I get a blank page, which means I do not get the related information for `somename.html`.

for example if i run `http://domain.com/index.php?url=somename.html` in the browser, I get the `{$body}` of the `somename.html` or `something.html` etc in my page.

but if i run `http://domain.com/somename.html` in the browser, I get nothing as it seems I do not have access to the `$url = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['url']);`

is there anything that I need to do with smarty PHP or htaccess file in order to make this work?

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED.

Comment: In your apache access logs , are browser requests to http://domain.com/somename.html showing up in the logs as a 404 or as a 500 error response? You have to figure out if the rewrite is working and if it is, what it actually gets rewritten as.

Comment: @Anthony, I get 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ index.php?url=$1
```

the `.html` is not included inside the `()` thus `$1` contains everything before the .html

e.g. `http://domain.com/somename.html` gets rewritten to `http://domain.com/index.php?url=somename`

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: The solution is to move the closing parenthesis to after the .html

Comment: no, but I've fixed it anyway. i was missing something in my php code.

Answer (score 1):

The better rewrite rule, per Pinoniq's answer, would be:

```
 RewriteRule ^([\w/]+\.html)$ index.php?url=$1
```

That should catch any alphanumerics plus the forward slash, and the `.html` but with the `.` escaped to avoid that headache.

Alternatively, you could also go with:

```
 RewriteRule ^([\w/]+).html$ index.php?url=$1.html
```

and just add the .html to the rewritten URL.